# What is a Spelling Bee Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a Word/Phrase™ series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of Phrase™ and Word™ puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Spelling Bee Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.
**Added more words here, which should help.**

| Spelling Bee Words™ | Not Spelling Bee Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| BEE | WASP |
| PER | EACH |
| DING | DONG |
| PING | TRACE |
| TOTAL | SUM |
| LEVER | KNOB |
| STRING | CORD |
| BUMBLE | BLUNDER |
| MISDEED | WRONG |
| SHEPHERD | TAMER |
| NONVIABLE | HEALTHY |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Spelling Bee Words™,Not Spelling Bee Words™
BEE,WASP
PER,EACH
DING,DONG
PING,TRACE
TOTAL,SUM
LEVER,KNOB
STRING,CORD
BUMBLE,BLUNDER
MISDEED,WRONG
SHEPHERD,TAMER
NONVIABLE,HEALTHY
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Spelling Bee Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of Spelling Bee Words™, many more exist.

Comment: I assume PONG is not a spelling be word?

Comment: Amusingly but probably irrelevantly, all of the following are words or have words that sound like them: bee-per, bee-ding, bee-ping, bee-lever. (You need to speak British rather than American English for that last one, I think.)

Comment: Hehe I think the OP is trying to trick us thinking that it's one rule, but it leads to a dead end.

Comment: There is just one rule. If you get partway through the list of Spelling Bee words with a rule that works and then you find the rest don't, you may be on the right track but aren't quite there.

Comment: Nonviable and healthy confuses me.

Comment: I'm going to guess.

Comment: I'm like 80% sure I've seen NONVIABLE in a wordplayish context before, but I can't at all remember where or what it was about.

Comment: The [tag:wordplay] tag is not set and was not an oversight.

Comment: @MMAdams PONG is not a Spelling Bee Word™.

Comment: I was using the term "wordplay" broadly rather than necessarily in line with the use of the tag here, but the clarification is noted :-).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A word is a Spelling Bee word if

> the name of its initial letter can be added to it (internally if need be) to make a new word.

Thus:

> BEE**BEE** (I'm not terribly sure about this one, I confess; is that really a word?)
>  **PEE**PER
>  **DEE**DING
>  **PEE**PING
>  **TEE**TOTAL
>  LEV**ELL**ER (or LEV**EL**ER if you prefer)
>  STR**ESS**ING
>  BUMBLE**BEE**
>  MISDE**EM**ED
>  SHEPHERD**ESS**
>  NON**EN**VIABLE

Here are some others:

> EMPLOY**EE** MORPH**EM**IC M**EM**O ROS**AR**Y

Comment: Nice job :)  my dictionary lists *beebee* so yeah.

Comment: It's annoying to have been so close so long ago.

Comment: Lemme guess - LEVER onward of the original list got ya?

Comment: Well, what was in my brain then was inadequate in two different ways (fixed versus varying, start versus anywhere -- I'm being slightly cryptic to reduce the danger of giving things away to other puzzlers) so maybe I shouldn't really say "so close". But it definitely feels as if I'd have got it days ago if I'd been just *slightly* less stupid.